# How to install dictionaries for GoldenDict?

Tags: software-installation, goldendict

After installing Ubuntu 13.04 the possibility to install dictionaries to GoldenDict is lost.

I downloaded a big collection for StarDict and usually copied it to the folder:
`/usr/share/stardict/dic/`. Next time after running GoldenDict it included these dictionaries automatically.

After installing 13.04 it doesn't work. I pressed <kbd>F3</kbd>, added this folder, selected "Recursive", pressed "Update" (maybe not precise translation from Ukrainian) - and nothing happened.

I tried to copy dictionaries to Home folder and added it - nothing happen.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The following command

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
sudo apt-get install goldendict-wordnet
```

will do.

> goldendict: dictionary lookup program.
>
> WordNet  is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs that are linked together by their semantic relationships

Answer (score 3):

Hope it will help you.....

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

Now to use the copyright free ‘GNU powered’ English dictionary (about 13MB of size … so it contains a lot) called “GCIDE” then use the below procedure to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install dict-gcide
```

Now launch goldendict.

Thats it.

Rference.... http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/12/how-to-setup-dictionary-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of GoldenDict. Fixed in the latest GoldenDict (apt repository version).

Comment: I used GoldenDict 3 month ago on Arch (so really up-to-date) and it was working well. Can't remember which version.

Answer (score 1):

open Dictionaries tab in edit> Dictionaries. Disable all other dictionaries by dragging and dropping into Inactive dictionaries. click apply and then ok. Close and reopen Goldendict.